# Android WebView won't load local files

Tags: android, html, css, webview, loading

I'm having a problem with Android WebView for my websites. When I open my site on any browser, the CSS style sheet, JavaScript and Images load. But when I open for example through Instagram (which uses WebView), I just have the html, naked.
I precise that all my links are in relative (I have a  tag which indicates from where to look for the files).

Here, my base is `<base href="http://anthony-e-b.rf.gd/" target="_top">`

and my CSS, my images, and my JS refer to this as:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">` (for the CSS).
Same for my pictures : `href="assets/pics/mon_image.jpg"`.

I do not understand, and although I search the Internet I do not see any solution ...
thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Hope it will help!